# Background and positioning problem mainly with CSS

Tags: html, css

```css
 *{        
              color: white;
              padding: 0;
              margin:0;
              box-sizing: border-box;
          }
            body{
             background-image: url(black-1072366_1920.jpg);  
            }
           
            #wrapper{
              
                width: 90%;
                height: auto;
               overflow: auto
            }
            
            #heading{
                
                width: 100%;
                font-size: 700%;
                color: red;
            }

          #text{
              
             float: left;
             border: 5px solid red;
          }
          
          #screen{
              width: 55%;
              height:auto;
              float: left;
              
              border: 5px solid red;
             
            
          }
         
          img{
             
              width:100%;
          }
```

```html
<body>
    <div id='wrapper'>
    <h1 id='heading'> Game Over</h1>    
        
   <div id-'text'>
    <p>
    Unlucky you failed on getting to the bus in time<br> <br> You have now missed the night out you've been looking <br> forward to for weeks. 
    <br>
    <br>    
    Well maybe next time will be a success!
       </p>    
        
  <ul> 
    <li>Flask Collected</li>
    <li> Keys Collected</li>
    <li>Wallet Collected</li>
    <li>Phone Collected</li>
    <li>Favourite Drink Collected</li>
  </ul>
        
       
    <p>Back to tv for tonight and the drawing board for the next outing!</p>   
       
    <a href="Victory.html">Play Again</a>
       <br>
        </div>
        
         <div id='screen'>
         <img src="room-2559790_1280.jpg">
         </div>
        
        </div>
```

So this is the code for a page i am doing and i am having some problems with backgrounds and getting the image to correctly sit next to the text.

I wanted to get the image to sit to the right of the text without using the position absolute or something similar. There should be a way to set it up so that the text and image sit beside each other but I guess I am doing it wrong.

So i want the text on the left and the image on the right side basically.

I thought float left might work but it did not seem to so I'm just wondering what I'm doing wrong.

The background is also repeating itself is their any way to stop this from happening in the link image down below it repeats itself and leaves a line. I'm just wondering how would you stop that.

Any help would be appreciated and i will try to answer quick if there are questions.

This is a basic page I just want the layout sorted before making it better.

[How it looks now](https://i.stack.imgur.com/PzC3I.jpg)

Comment: Wrap the image and text in a div, then put `display: flex;` on the div

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use `display: flex;` to align the image to the right of the text.

For the background repeating, you can fix it by specifying background size, position, and repeat.

All the stuff you wanted should be included below :)

```css
* {
  color: white;
  padding: 0;
  margin: 0;
  box-sizing: border-box;
}

body {
  background-image: url(black-1072366_1920.jpg);
  background-color: black;
  background-size:cover;
  background-position: center center;
  background-repeat: no-repeat;
}

#wrapper {
  width: 90%;
  height: auto;
  overflow: auto
}

#heading {
  width: 100%;
  font-size: 700%;
  color: red;
}

#text {
  float: left;
  border: 5px solid red;
}

#screen {
  width: 55%;
  height: auto;
  float: left;
  border: 5px solid red;
}

img {
  width: 100%;
}

.main {
display: flex;
}
```

```html
<div id='wrapper'>
  <h1 id='heading'> Game Over</h1>

  <div class="main">
    <div id="text">
      <p>
        Unlucky you failed on getting to the bus in time<br> <br> You have now missed the night out you've been looking <br> forward to for weeks.
        <br>
        <br> Well maybe next time will be a success!
      </p>

      <ul>
        <li>Flask Collected</li>
        <li> Keys Collected</li>
        <li>Wallet Collected</li>
        <li>Phone Collected</li>
        <li>Favourite Drink Collected</li>
      </ul>


      <p>Back to tv for tonight and the drawing board for the next outing!</p>

      <a href="Victory.html">Play Again</a>
      <br>
    </div>

    <div id='screen'>
      <img src="room-2559790_1280.jpg">
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```